# Flutter searchable_dropdown hide keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart

I using searchable_dropdown https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown

How can I show the keyboard **only** when the user touch the input text field?

All the examples are showing that the keyboard show up as soon as the user click the dropdownbotton.

If you check the searchable_dropdown.dart that belongs to the package the **keyboard focus is set to true**.

```
  Widget searchBar() {
    return new Container(
      child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new TextField(
            controller: txtSearch,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32, vertical: 12)),
            autofocus: true,
```

How can I show the keyboard **only** when the user touch the input text field?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `searceable_dropdown.dart` look for the `searchBar` widget and change the autofocus to `false` Dont forget to run `pub get`

```
 Widget searchBar() {
    return new Container(
      child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new TextField(
            controller: txtSearch,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32, vertical: 12)),
            autofocus: false,//Here change from true to false
            onChanged: (value) {
              _updateShownIndexes(value);
              setState(() {});
            },
            keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
          ),
          new Positioned(
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: new Center(
              child: new Icon(
                Icons.search,
                size: 24,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          txtSearch.text.isNotEmpty
              ? new Positioned(
                  right: 0,
                  top: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: new Center(
                    child: new InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        _updateShownIndexes('');
                        setState(() {
                          txtSearch.text = '';
                        });
                      },
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32)),
                      child: new Container(
                        width: 32,
                        height: 32,
                        child: new Center(
                          child: new Icon(
                            Icons.close,
                            size: 24,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : new Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Go to searchable_dropdown.dart class. At line 871 or 877 there will be autofocus: true. Just convert true => fasle. Close project and restart.
This will work.

Comment: Not a good solution, because in the future when we need to update the package, this fix will disapear. But thanks for commenting :)